# iPad restrictions in the UAE

Tags: ios, ipad, internationalization, apple-store, applecare

I'm looking at buying a new iPad (M1 Air version) and I have two options: either from the UAE or one that's imported from the US.

The one on the UAE is actually cheaper (special circumstances) and I can get it faster. But I heard there used to be restrictions on UAE hardware, e.g. you can't install FaceTime and maybe other apps, so I would definitely prefer to pay a little more for one that's full-featured (i.e. the US one).

My question is: are there still any restrictions on Apple devices bought in the UAE? Or do they work exactly like the ones in the US now?

**EDIT**: I respectfully disagree with the close reason as it references an 8-year old question and things may have changed significantly in the meantime.

Indeed, I went to the Apple Store today, and the salesman there told me that as long as I setup the iPad for my region (i.e. not UAE) then there'll be absolutely no restrictions at all. I explicitly asked about FaceTime and they said while it would not work in the UAE, it would work elsewhere. Furthermore, while I have [read](https://techandcoolstuff.com/is-iphone-warranty-international/) that devices bought in the UAE are not covered by international warranty, the salesman told me exactly the contrary, that they do have global warranty.

Now pardon me if I'm skeptical as I've had many salesmen tell me exactly what I wanted to hear in order to close a sale, only to figure out later that wasn't exactly true. So I was looking from updated information from other users with first-hand experience, who have actually bought Apple devices in the UAE recently (say 2022 or 2023), whether the restrictions still exist or not.

Comment: Just a quick glance, it appears there are differences with FaceTime, ApplePay and some location based services.  Likely everything is related to export restrictions

Comment: Lots to think about. I would expect (no first hand info): If it is services and apps which are blocked in UAE, then source of device should not matter. What you can access may depend on country of your Apple ID and any country wide firewall - so it can be complicated with a US Apple ID in a restrictive country.  You also need to ask yourself which country's consumer legislation and Apple warranty do you want to be under - probably depends on how soon (if ever) you might leave UAE.

Comment: The Apple references in the duplicate question are still live - so the information in the duplicate is still up to date.